# reactjs components errors with unmounted

Tags: reactjs

from start with a reactjs i have one this problem that i cant solve. I tried so many examples from internet but i couldnt find the right way to write this code. I have more components like this for users,companies and other thing but in all i getting :

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('visiotrsnumber', (data) => {
       if (mounted.current === true) setVisitorsNumber(data)
    })
    socket.on('loggedlist', (data) => {
      if (mounted.current === true) setLoggedList(data)
    })
  }, []);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          'http://localhost:5000/api/users?page=1'
        );
        
        if (mounted.current === true){
          setLoadedUsers(responseData.pageOfItems);
          setTotalArticles(responseData.pager.totalItems);
          setPage(responseData.pager.currentPage);
        }   
      } catch (err) {}
  };

  const fetchUsersSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const responseData = await sendRequest(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/users/search?search=${encodeURI(searchTerm)}&page=1`
      );
      
      if (mounted.current === true){
        setLoadedUsers(responseData.pageOfItems);
        setTotalArticles(responseData.pager.totalItems);
        setPage(responseData.pager.currentPage);  
      }
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    !searchTerm ? fetchUsers() : fetchUsersSearch()     


    return () => {
      mounted.current=false;
    }    
  },[searchTerm, sendRequest]);
```

If someone got some example how should i write this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either you use one component wide flag or you use one flag per each `useEffect` hook with cleanup callback. Here is a sketch for both options:

- component wide flag

```
const mounted = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  mounted.current = true;
  return () => mounted.current = false;
}, []);

// ...and usage example...
const fetchUsers = async () => {
  try {
    const responseData = await sendRequest('http://localhost:5000/api/users');
    if (mounted.current) {
      setLoadedUsers(responseData.pageOfItems);
    }
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

- one flag per each `useEffect` hook with cleanup callback

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('visitorsnumber', setVisitorsNumber);
  socket.on('loggedlist', setLoggedList);
  return () => {
    socket.off('visitorsnumber', setVisitorsNumber);
    socket.off('loggedlist', setLoggedList);
  };
}, []);

const fetchUsers = async (token) => {
  try {
    const responseData = await sendRequest('http://localhost:5000/api/users');
    if (token.current) {
      setLoadedUsers(responseData.pageOfItems);
    }
  } catch (error) {}
};

useEffect(() => {
  const token = { current: true };
  if (searchTerm)
    fetchUsersSearch(token);
  else
    fetchUsers(token);
  return () => token.current = false;
}, [searchTerm, sendRequest]);
```

Personally I consider the second approach cleaner. It has the added benefit of preventing outdated responses from overriding newer results.

Comment: Thank you very much for detail answer i used the second example but, if i post like your code it says me the token is defined did you miss maybe to define in on top of file or something?

Comment: I create the token in the useEffect and propagate it into the fetch code.

Comment: My mistake was, I didn't copy the code well, now I did everything according to your example, but again it throws out the same error ... https://imgur.com/OrzYPqr

Comment: Are you sure you safeguarded all your fetching code in all your components? Go through your code thorougly and look for all places that need such a flag.

Comment: Please do your own debugging. You can start by commenting out some inner component and see if the warning is gone. From there subsequently pull more code in until you have all your code commented in again.

Comment: Just want to say i was debugging whole day and i fixed all the errors, thank you so much for examples now i figure how to deal with this. Best regards